# Error during Building Chromium_org_openmax_dl for Android Lollipop

Tags: android

I'm on fresh Ubuntu 14.10 64 Bit.
I followed the How to from here: https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html 
 to set my system for building.

I'm getting following error: http://pastie.org/9711240

Why I'm asking here?

I know that they are custom ROM's, but I'm getting same error for 2 completely different sources (CM and SlimRoms) while other users building without issues..

Does possible to be a something OS related? Maybe some idea where to look...

Every help is really appreciated..

Thanx in advance :)

EDIT: I found that gcc version on Ubuntu 14.10 is:

```
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 
doc@doc-UbuntU:~$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
doc@doc-UbuntU:~$
```

But expecte4d from build enviroinment is GCC 4.8:

```
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-w64-mingw32-4.8/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-
```

The question now is How to switch to gcc 4.8 on Ubuntu 14.10?

Any ideas?